# Auto minify Javascript/CSS files after update?

Tags: php, javascript, automation, minify

I know of ways to minify JS and CSS files but is there a way to auto-minify these files in the production system? For instance, I modify something inside the original JS files and update the production environment. However, while using the JS files, it should use an auto-minified version of the JS file (preferably update the current minified version if the source files changed).

Considering that I work in both Unix and Windows environment, writing a bash script did not seem like a plausible idea. So anything that is OS independent or maybe something that uses PHP initially to do this would be great. Any suggestions?

Comment: See this related questions: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853295/javascript-build-tools - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222581/python-script-for-minifying-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find value in [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/). It uses PHP5, and can sit well on your production server.

From the website:

> It combines multiple CSS or Javascript files, removes unnecessary whitespace and comments, and serves them with gzip encoding and optimal client-side cache headers.

Comment: It appears that [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) is not Google's. It is merely hosted on Google Code.

Comment: Please provide details, Links may die!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @RC, read those existing Q/As.

Also other options for your specific question:

- Post-Commit hook - minify step
- Build step during development, commit minified files
- Server side filter that minifies on file change (Rails and other frameworks have this built in)
- Enhance you deployment script to do the minify during deployment

Write these hooks in a cross platform language instead of bash. (JavaScript, Python, Ruby, etc).