# How to improve Performance in ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

We have migrated one classic ASP application to ASP.net2010 using C#. 
Compare to the classic ASP application the newly migrated application's performance is bit slow.

Which areas need to be checked to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

Run a profiler on it. I use JetBrain's. It will pin point the places in code that are the slowest.

Check your data access. In conversions like this, I've seen that as the major area of issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable viewstate on pages and or controls that don't need it and follow all the advice given here: [ASP.NET: how to load page faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082769/asp-net-how-to-load-page-faster/8083096#8083096)

Answer (score 1):

1. Page.IsPostBack Property
2. Enable Buffering
3. Remove unused HttpModules
4. Trim Page Sizes
5. Use a CDN
6. Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect
7. Precompiling
8. Session State Management
9. ViewState
10. Caching
11. Locking and Shared Resources

Answer (score 0):

this [post](http://www.realsoftwaredevelopment.com/20-tips-to-improve-aspnet-application-performance/) explains a 20 tips to improve asp.net performance

mainly you will find tips like reduce usage of sessions and ViewState.. keep page size small 
don't include any css styles or javascripts in the page markup.